# How can I refuse a review board request?

Tags: review-board

The problem is that I want to add some constraints when using the `post-review` , for example if my python file does not match pep8, I want the request to be automatically refused. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is only on your machine, then you can write a script that checks for all the required conditions and then calls post-review. If you want to enforce this on all the users, then you can distribute the script to all the clients or add these check in the server.

There is no implicit way to do this using post-review.